# Windows 8.1: Storage spaces, storage pool, resiliancy: confused

Tags: windows-8.1, storage-pool

I have two identical external 2TB USB drives and want to combine them using the native storage pool for redundancy (Mirrored, so either drive can fail and data will be safe). However, I don't know if I've set it up correctly. The screen shot below shows the setup:

[image]

Please could someone confirm that I have set this up correctly?

Thanks

Comment: The screenshot clearly indicates you have create a two-way mirror `storage space`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: The setup options were a bit confusing, I just wanted to make 100% sure given the importance of a working backup. Thank you

Comment: I hope you understand you should make this Storage Space your only backup.  People have loss their data in the past.  Like all data solutions you should have multiple backups.